# WebView ceding rel=external links to Activity Manager

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, rel, webviewclient

I have a `WebView` wherein I would like anchor tags with `rel=external` to open in the Android browser but all other links to stay in the `WebView`.

So the content will load within the `WebView` if the user taps a link whose markup looks like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/">Whatever</a>
```

But the content will load in the Android browser if the user taps a link whose markup looks like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/" rel="external">Whatever</a>
```

Here's my relevant code (with one bit of pseudocode identified with a comment) in the `WebViewClient` code:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (! rel=external) {   //  <-- That condition...how do I do that?
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

Would the best way to determine whether there is a `rel=external` attribute/value be to somehow use `addJavascriptInterface()` and have JavaScript inform Java whether or not there is a `rel` attribute and what the value is?

Or is there a better way?

(I am looking for a solution that does not involve checking the domain of the URL because there are an arbitrary number of domains that need to be treated as internal and that I cannot know in advance or determine easily on-the-fly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a variation of your original suggestion is probably best if you don't want to modify the existing URL.

Use `addJavaScriptInterface` to add a class to handle your external URL loading. An inner class might look like this:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    public void viewExternalUrl(String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And of course adding it:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "Android");
```

Inject JavaScript to add click handlers to call your JavaScript interface after the page is loaded (using JQuery for simplicity's sake) through `loadUrl`. You can detect the page load finishing by creating a custom [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and overriding [`onPageFinished`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    private static final String sJs = "javascript:" +
        Uri.encode("$('a[@rel$='external']').click(function(){ Android.viewExternalUrl($(this).attr('href')); });");

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl(sJs);
    }
}
```

I haven't tested any of this code, but it should work, assuming you have JQuery loaded in the page. If not, you can probably come up with some JavaScript to manipulate the DOM without it or you can use loadUrl to manually load JQuery first before the loading the JavaScript.

*Note that this approach completely abandons any use of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`*

Comment: This looks very promising.  Didn't realize that it would mean I'd not be able to use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` but that's not a problem for me at all.

Comment: Well, you could still use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` for other stuff if you wanted to. In fact, you could probably change it so that you signal the JavaScript interface from the JavaScript that injects via `loadUrl` to tell your Java code which URL is external, store that in some sort of table and then do a lookup when `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is called, but I find that unnecessarily complicated and possibly error prone (what if you have two links to the same URL, but only one is ref=external? Can't see why that'd happen, but if it did, it would break).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use a different way of designating external URLs... one that embeds that info in the URL and hence is compatible with the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function. Specifically, create custom scheme URLs and pass the real page as a parameter:

myappname://external?url=encoded_real_page_url

Then in the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function check if it's a custom scheme URL, extract the url param, decode it and then redirect.

Comment: The pages that I'm viewing in the WebView need to be viewable by standard browsers too, so I'll need to work around that issue if I go this route.  Perhaps I can have my app inject JavaScript into each page as its loaded that will rewrite the URLs with the custom scheme. If not, then perhaps I can try to deal with it on the server side (e.g., sniff the user agent for my app and render the URLs accordingly). I'd rather not, but it should work.  +1

Comment: To figure out whether the HTML is in your app's webview, you can add a special marker JS interface to the webview (with a bool function to call, if you're extra paranoid about possible false positives) and implement the check for that in the JavaScript. Then, if the marker is present you could modify all URLs via JavaScript on load. Or have each link be like javascript::link_fn(pageUrl) and use link_fn to check for the marker interface and then determine how to put together the URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the server side content, then definitely go with the suggestion Theo made. Since you indicate the pages should also load in standard browers, don't use a custom scheme, but make `rel=external` part of the actual url you're linking/redirecting to.

By doing that, you can easily parse the `url` parameter in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` and check for above key/value pair. I would suggest you parse it into a [`Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) and use [`getQueryParameter(key)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getQueryParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to check for the value matching `rel`. If it's `external`, fire off an Intent.

It would look something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    String relValue = uri.getQueryParameter("rel");    
    if (relValue != null && !relValue.equals("external")) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

On a side note: no need to declare an 'else' since you already return from the method in the 'if'.

If users can go to any site using your WebView and if you're paranoid about other sites applying the same key/value pair for their purposes, you could easily add another check to determine whether the url is on 'your' domain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sample code (and the side note, which I appreciate!).  Regarding the check for domain suggestion at the end, please do note the last paragraph of the question:  (I am looking for a solution that does not involve checking the domain of the URL because there are an arbitrary number of domains that need to be treated as internal and that I cannot know in advance or determine easily on-the-fly.)